# How to verify particular values in JSON response - Postman

Tags: postman, json

The response body looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "wardName": "Unit1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "wardName": "Unit2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "wardName": "Unit3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "wardName": "Unit4"
    }
]
```

Here, I need to verify whether the ward names (Unit1, Unit2, Unit3, and Unit4) have correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Postman test](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#testing-response-body):

```
pm.test("Checking wardNames", () => {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(responseJson[0].wardName).to.eql(Unit1);
  pm.expect(responseJson[1].wardName).to.eql(Unit2);
  pm.expect(responseJson[2].wardName).to.eql(Unit3);
  pm.expect(responseJson[3].wardName).to.eql(Unit4);
});
```

Of course, you can code these assertions differently as you want.

Comment: Hi Joāo, Thank you for the answer. I have tried with that but gives the following error.                                                   
"Checking wardNames | TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: @kasunigunasekera: there should be no `list`, the array from the response is already accessible through `responseBody`, so `pm.expect(responseJson[0].wardName).to.eql('Unit1');` is how to write these checks. Also `eql()` has to take a string, `Unit1` without quotes will try to find a variable with such a name. More on that in Postman docs https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/

Comment: Yeah, I assumed there would be some object of type list, not a list on the root of a JSON object - this design is odd.